# HTML & CSS - Centering an image carousel within its container

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I've created a kind of image carousel effect but want to try figure out how to center it within it's container.

Not sure if this will be possible as the overflow is hidden but any suggestions or workarounds would be really appreciated.

```js
function slide(){
  var first = $('.slider_img').first();
  first.animate({opacity: '0', width: '0px'}, function() {
    first.appendTo('#slider').css({opacity: '1', width: 'auto'});
  });
  var slider_timeout = setTimeout(function(){slide()} , 3000);
}
slide();
```

```css
#slider_container{
  position:relative;
  width:80%;
  height:50px;
  background-color:#fff;
  box-shadow:0px 0px 10px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
  overflow:hidden;
}
#slider{
  /* center */
}
#slider img{
  display:inline-block;
  margin:0px 5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="slider_container">
  <div id="slider">
    <img class="slider_img" src="https://via.placeholder.com/100x50?text=1">
    <img class="slider_img" src="https://via.placeholder.com/100x50?text=2">
    <img class="slider_img" src="https://via.placeholder.com/100x50?text=3">
    <img class="slider_img" src="https://via.placeholder.com/100x50?text=4">
    <img class="slider_img" src="https://via.placeholder.com/100x50?text=5">
    <img class="slider_img" src="https://via.placeholder.com/100x50?text=6">
    <img class="slider_img" src="https://via.placeholder.com/100x50?text=7">
    <img class="slider_img" src="https://via.placeholder.com/100x50?text=8">
    <img class="slider_img" src="https://via.placeholder.com/100x50?text=9">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Have you tried #slider_container { text-align: center; }?

Comment: would you please explain which overflow are you talking about. i am not clear about your question. Thanks :)

Comment: Sorry made a mistake... this is all being generated in PHP and there was just an issue with how it was all generated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this? This version is using flexbox with `justify-content: center;`

```js
function slide(){
  var first = $('.slider_img').first();
  first.animate({opacity: '0', width: '0px'}, function() {
    first.appendTo('#slider').css({opacity: '1', width: 'auto'});
  });
  var slider_timeout = setTimeout(function(){slide()} , 3000);
}
slide();
```

```css
#slider_container {
  position: relative;
  width: 80%;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: #fff;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
  overflow: hidden;
}

#slider {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

#slider img {
  flex-shrink: 0;
  margin: 0px 5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="slider_container">
  <div id="slider">
    <img class="slider_img" src="https://via.placeholder.com/100x50?text=1">
    <img class="slider_img" src="https://via.placeholder.com/100x50?text=2">
    <img class="slider_img" src="https://via.placeholder.com/100x50?text=3">
    <img class="slider_img" src="https://via.placeholder.com/100x50?text=4">
    <img class="slider_img" src="https://via.placeholder.com/100x50?text=5">
    <img class="slider_img" src="https://via.placeholder.com/100x50?text=6">
    <img class="slider_img" src="https://via.placeholder.com/100x50?text=7">
    <img class="slider_img" src="https://via.placeholder.com/100x50?text=8">
    <img class="slider_img" src="https://via.placeholder.com/100x50?text=9">
  </div>
</div>
```